# How to "POST" ndb.StructuredProperty?

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints-proto-datastore

## Problem:

I have following `EndpointsModels`,

```
class Role(EndpointsModel):
    label = ndb.StringProperty()
    level = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Application(EndpointsModel):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    roles = ndb.StructuredProperty(Role, repeated=True)
```

and an API method:

```
class ApplicationApi(protorpc.remote.Service):
    @Application.method(http_method="POST",
                        request_fields=('name', 'roles'),
                        name="create",
                        path="applications")
    def ApplicationAdd(self, instance):
        return instance
```

When I try to POST this data:

```
{ "name": "test", "roles": [{ "label": "test", "level": 0 }] }
```

I'm getting an error ( [trace](http://pastebin.com/raw/Z15SfW7E) ):

> AttributeError: 'Role' object has no attribute '_Message__decoded_fields'

## Workaround:

I tried to use `EndpointsAliasProperty`:

```
class ApplicationApi(protorpc.remote.Service):
    ...
    def roless_set(self, value):
        logging.info(value)
        self.roles = DEFAULT_ROLES

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=roless_set)
    def roless(self):
        return getattr(self, 'roles', [])
```

which results in `400 BadRequest`

> Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Expected type `<type 'unicode'>` for field roless, found {u'level': 0, u'label': u'test'} (type `<type 'dict'>`))

If I add `property_type` to the alias:

```
    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=roless_set, property_type=Role)
```

I'm getting server error again ( [trace](http://pastebin.com/raw/7UbLvmJb) ):

> TypeError: Property field must be either a subclass of a simple ProtoRPC field, a ProtoRPC enum class or a ProtoRPC message class. Received Role`<label=StringProperty('label'), level=IntegerProperty('level')>`.

<strike>Is there a way to "convert" `EndpointsModel` to `ProtoRPC message class`?</strike> Are there any better solutions for creating models with `StructuredProperty` using POST data? I couldn't find any examples for this, if someone knows any links, please share (:

#### UPDATE:

After some digging through source code, I found `EndpointsModel.ProtoModel()` that can be used to convert ndb.Model to ProtoRPC message class

```
    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=roless_set, property_type=Role.ProtoModel())
```

This resolves issue with `EndpointsAliasProperty` workaround, but the problem remains...

Answer (score 0):

Check this repo: https://github.com/zdenulo/epd-error-example.
Here I was demonstrating error in endpoints-proto-datastore which in latest version should be fixed. So upgrade in repository to latest  endpoints-proto-datastore and you should have working example which similar to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Sasxa has there been a fix for this as far as you know? I am currently dealing with the same issue, and I can start a new thread for this discussion if nothing has been found.

*Update:* created a [new issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36241087/post-an-ndb-structuredproperty-message-decoded-fields) linked to this one

**Update:** This issue has been resolved! You can check out the issue [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/143).