# Post an ndb StructuredProperty _Message__decoded_fields

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

### **My Problem:**

I am attempting to fill a datastore model in GAE that contains an ndb.Structured Property() using a 'POST' request.

This question has been asked recently but not answered ([How to “POST” ndb.StructuredProperty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35673294/how-to-post-ndb-structuredproperty/36240244#36240244))

**I have the following two models:**

```
class Check(EndpointsModel):
    this = ndb.StringProperty()
    that = ndb.StringProperty()

class CheckMessage(EndpointsModel):
    check = ndb.StructuredProperty(Check)
```

**I'm trying to post this data:**

```
{
    check:
    {
        "this":"test",
        "that":"test"
    }
}
```

**with the following API request:**

```
@CheckMessage.method(name='check_insert',path='check/insert',http_method='POST')
    def check_insert(self,request):
        print(request)
```

**Upon posting from the client I receive the following [error:](http://pastebin.com/raw/SfvBNDyP)**

```
AttributeError: 'Check' object has no attribute '_Message__decoded_fields'
```

### **The Issue:**

From my very high-level understanding of the endpoints-proto-datastore module it seems that when the json is being decoded and saved onto the incoming message (utils.py line 431) it's not checking for structured/localstructured properties and saving their keys as well which is all fine and dandy until FromValue (ndb/model.py line 115) checks for instances of structured properties and attempts to recursively convert the structured property from the protorpc message into a model entity (which needs the _Message__decoded_fields).

**Sasxa** (see the link above) had found a nifty little workaround to this issue by using an EndpointsAliasProperty converted to a ProtoRPC message class to bypass endpoints-proto-datastore's automatic conversion of the structuredproperty into its associated model entity, however this workaround had some side effects that made what I was trying to do difficult.

### **The Question:**

Does anyone know how to **correctly** fill a datastore model containing a StructuredProperty using a 'POST' request, and are there any working examples of this available?

Comment: Filed https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/issues/143

Comment: Fix implemented: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-proto-datastore/pull/144